# Confusion on Perceptron Functions

Tags: math, machine-learning, logic, artificial-intelligence, perceptron

I am trying to understand how perceptrons function by working them out by hand, but my results are not matching how a perceptron should function. I’m running on the assumption that the following steps should yield results that imitate a perceptron:

1. Take each input individually as xᵢ & yᵢ
2. Multiply each input by a (W₁ for X and W₂ for Y)
3. Combine xᵢ•W₁ & yᵢ•W₂ by addition = Rᵢ
4. Apply a piecewise function to the result with a randomized switching threshold.

*(as I’m doing this by hand, there’s no need for a piecewise... I’ll just be looking for a point at which the result ‘R’ splits between my two data sets.)

Here (https://m.imgur.com/gallery/SII1r) is my graph of X,Y coordinates, split into a red dataset and a blue dataset. The goal would obviously by to identify a pattern in the result R that would be interpreted correctly by a classifier.

Here are the data sets and their resulting R values with (W₁ = -1) & (W₂ = +1):

Blue Data set -

```
Y   4.   3.   2.   1.    0.   4.   3.   2.   1.   
X.  1.   2.   3.   4.    5.   2.   3.   4.   5.

R.  3.   1.  -1.  -3.   -5.   2.   0.  -2.  -4
```

Red Data set -

```
Y.  3.  2.   1.   0.  2   1.   0.   1.  0.    
X.  1.  2.   3.   4.  1.  2.   3.   1.  2.

R.  2.  0.  -2.  -4.  1. -1.  -3.   0. -2
```

From these results, that clearly overlap in R values, there’s no way to write a piece-wise that distinguishes between the Red and Blue dataset. My impression is that a perceptron is meant to take a set of linearly separable 2D (or greater) values and collapse them into a set of 1D values... almost like placing the R values on a number line and finding where the data sets split up. I know I’m doing something seriously wrong with my math or interpretation of how the perceptron functions, but my hope is to understand it at it’s most basic level.... so if anyone can point out where I’ve fallen short, it would be greatly appreciated! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your problem statement: the correct `W` values for this are w1 = w2 = 1.  The split in R values is Rred < 4.5 < Rblue.

How did you obtain the given `W` coefficients?

Comment: Wow Prune! Thank you very much! To be honest, I picked a few weights at random... ranging from (-1 & +1) to (1 & 0.75). I don't know why I never tried coefficients that were equal. However, I'm still left wondering how the perceptron determines whether the slope of the separation line is positive or negative. Would it be accurate to say that the perceptron can't determine +/- slope because the output contains data that is only separated 1-Dimensionally (can't...at least without working backwards and attempting to use the calculated slope on the input data w/ the original number of dimensions)?

Comment: The perceptron gets trained by back-propagation from the output labels (probably -1 for blue, +1 for red).

Comment: So back-propagation is the process of applying the output labels to the original dataset with the original number of dimensions to determine the most accurate slope formula??

Comment: Yes; there is a *lot* of documentation on the training process on line.

Comment: Thank You Very Much! I really appreciate your help!